# MAUI password field broke after Android update

Tags: android, xml, maui

I have a MAUI app with a simple screen like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="gfMobile.MainPage">

<ScrollView>
    <VerticalStackLayout
        Spacing="25"
        Padding="30,0"
        VerticalOptions="Center">

        <Label
            Text="Enter password"
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Entry
            IsPassword="true"
            x:Name="password"
            Text=""
            SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
            SemanticProperties.Description=""
            FontSize="18"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Button
            x:Name="send"
            Text="Send"
            SemanticProperties.Hint="send"
            Clicked="OnBtnClicked"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This used to work (on both emulator and physical device) as intended while I was running it on Android 10 (API 29). On Android 11 (API 30) both emulator and device the Entry (password) field breaks, as if the IsPassword="true" tag wasn't even there, all entered characters are plainly visible.

So far I tried to see if there's additional formatting requirements, the bool value of "true" is not case sensitive and the linebreaks are not an issue. I tried removing the other tags, that also didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what caused the aberrant behavior still, but the fix was to try to send the form once. After that the field started working normally.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version.

There are some known issues about `Entry`, you can check them here:

[Entry: changing IsPassword false to true, does not show the numbers, when Keyboard attribute is "Numeric"](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/10407)

[Cursor jumps on Entry with IsPassword](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5401).

[Entry with IsPassword="True" does not work correctly](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7334)

Comment: I tried that and had to immediately roll the update back, because it removed some important dependancy. My previously working project suddenly had about 150 build errors after the update.